# How can I map each specific row value to an ID in Pentaho?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I’m new to Pentaho and I’m currently having an issue with mapping specific row values to an ID.

I have a data file with around 30 columns, one of which is for currencies (USD, GBP, AUD, etc).
The main objective is to have the user select up to 8 (minimum of 1) currencies and map them to a corresponding ID 1-8. All other currencies not in the specified 8 will be mapped with an ID of 9.
The final step is to then output the original data set, along with the IDs.

I’m pretty sure I’m making this way harder than it should, but here is what I have at the moment.

I have created a job where the first step is to set the variables for my 8 currencies, selectionOne -> AUD, selectionTwo -> GBP, …, selectionEight -> JPY.

I then have a transformation to read the data from the file and use the copy rows to result step.

Following that I have a second job called for-each which is my loop for checking the current currency in the row.
Within this job I have two transformations, one called **set-current**, one called **map-currencies**.

set-current simply uses the get rows from result step (to grab the data from the first transformation). I then use the set variable step to set the **current** currency to the value in currency field. This works fine, as each pass through in the loop changes the current variable to the correct value.

Map-currencies is where I’m having the most issues.
The goal is to use the filter row step to compare the current currency against the original 8 selected currencies, and then using the value mapper step to map it to an ID, before outputting the csv file.

The main issue here, is that I can’t use my original variables in the filter or value mapper.
So, what I’ve done here is use the get variables step to retrieve the variables and named them: one, two, three, …, eight. This allows me to bypass the filtering issue, but they don’t seem to work for the value mapper, which is the all important step.

The second issue is that when the file is output it only outputs one value (because of the loop), selecting the append option works, but this could be a problem if the job is run more than once.
However, the priority here is the mapping issue.

I understand that this is rather long, and perhaps a tad confusing, but I will greatly appreciate any help on this, even if it’s an entirely new approach .

Like I said, I’m probably making it harder than it should be.

Thanks for your time.

Edit for AlainD

[Input example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afgQu.png)

[Output example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nPTC.png)

Comment: use `Stream lookup` step, you can setup default '9' for those without in lookup table. Lookup step can be a 'Data Grid' step to save currency<->id mapping.

Comment: How and when is the user supposed to provide the mapping? Is it at runtime, through parameters passed to the job or in a file/table somewhere?

Comment: Please give a 4 rows / 3 columns example of your Input and expected Output. And  also answer Cyrus: how do you plan to provide the mapping?

Comment: Hey Cyrus. I have created a new properties file, so that the currency values can be changed at any time, and so that the transformation is independent from the Pentaho variables (I created those merely for testing if the mapping works). However, the issue still stands. I'm having an issue with accessing the properties and comparing the current row value against those specified in the properties file.

Comment: Hey AlainD. I have added a small example of the input and expected output. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This should be doable in a single transformation using the Stream Lookup step.

[image: stream lookup step diagram]

Text File Input is your main file, Property input reads your property file into Key and Value columns. You could use a normal text file with two columns instead of the property input.

Below are the settings of the Stream lookup. Note the default value "9" for records that are not found in the lookup stream.

[image: Stream lookup step configuration]

Comment: This worked!! Thank you so much. I was totally making way harder than it should have been. Thanks again, I really appreciate it.